# Webmatrix 2 template creation failure

Tags: webmatrix, webmatrix-2

I'm having problems creating sites from templates using the latest version of WebMatrix. I have uninstalled it and retried a few times restarting my computer as well but still it fails to create a template. I have tried to create ASP.NET, Node.js templates which result in the same error ("Method failed with unexpected error code 50"). Googling hasn't helped.

The details in the log file are:

EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: Method failed with unexpected error code 50.
   at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName, ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object exceptionContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FileSystemSecurityEx..ctor(Boolean isContainer, String name, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean isDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SetAclProvider.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.Add(DeploymentObject source, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAdd(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleUpdate(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(String provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentWellKnownProvider provider, String path, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)
   at Microsoft.Web.PlatformInstaller.MSDeployProxy.Install(InstallerContext context, RemoteCredentials remoteCredentials)

Any ideas?

Comment: Greetings!  We think this has something to do with permissions on the folder where we're trying to create new sites: ~/Documents/My Web Sites.  By chance, are you using IntelliMirror or writing to shared documents?

Comment: Hey Justin, Sorry for the very, very late response. No I wasn't using IntelliMirror. I suspect it was something to do with the way my PC has been set up. My Documents folder points to a file share located on some corporate server somewhere which maybe why I was getting issues.

I just assumed it was a conflict between VS2012 and WebMatrix so I just stuck to using VS2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided against using WebMatrix. As per my comment to Justin Beckwith I stuck to using VS2012 after assuming the error was down to:

1. My Documents folder being hosted on a file share somewhere
2. Or a conflict with VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

In WebMatrix quick start go to Options -> Site and change your default site location to a local file path.